# After executing stored procedure with `ExecuteSqlRaw` in Entity Framework Core showing error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

The error I get is:

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not SqlParameter objects.

after I run this code:

```
var sqlparamPayRunId = new SqlParameter("@PayRunId", payRunId);
sqlparamPayRunId.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt;
CRMDbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC DeletePayRun @PayRunId", sqlparamPayRunId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error with EFCore5, and I changed the sqlParameter namespace from *System.Data.SqlClient* to *Microsoft.Data.SqlClient*.